# Multiplying Fractions and Integers in Python

Tags: python, rational-numbers

I'm trying to build a rational numbers class that will perform various arithmetic functions based on input values without using the `fractions` module.  When I'm using two different fractions the code works fine, but as soon as I try to use an integer I'm getting errors in earlier class functions and am unsure why.  What I'm trying to implement at this point is, again, adding an integer to a rational number (e.g., `print Rational(1,2) * 3`).

I've included the code that I have thus far below - the problematic operation is `__radd__`, though when this is included in my code I receive an attribute error for `__add__` (this error does not show up until this new operation is included).  I'm guessing the problem comes from still having the 2nd `__radd__` parameter as other (assuming a different case of the Rational class?), but am unsure how to proceed.

Edit: I'm using Python 2.7.  The error from a sample run is included below the code.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a%b)
class Rational:
    def __init__(self, nom, denom):
        if denom == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError, ("Cannot divide by zero!")
        else:
            self.reduce = gcd(nom, denom)
            self.nom = nom / self.reduce
            self.denom = denom / self.reduce
    def __add__ (self, other):
        return Rational(self.nom*other.denom+other.nom*self.denom, self.denom*other.denom)        
    def __sub__ (self, other):
        return Rational(self.nom * other.denom - other.nom * self.denom,self.denom * other.denom)    
    def __mul__ (self, other):
        return Rational(self.nom * other.nom, self.denom * other.denom)
    def __div__ (self, other):
        return Rational(self.nom * other.denom, self.denom * other.nom)
    def __radd__ (self, other):
        return Rational(self.nom*1+other*self.denom, self.denom*1) 
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.nom) + "/" + str(self.denom)
```

## Sample error

```
print Rational(1,2) + 1

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-1ccb1fc0dfef> in <module>()
----> 1 print Rational(1,2) + 1

C:\Users\turk\Documents\EV_HW6_P2.py in __add__(self, other)
     13             self.denom = denom / self.reduce
     14     def __add__ (self, other):
---> 15         return Rational(self.nom*other.denom+other.nom*self.denom, self.denom*other.denom)
     16     def __sub__ (self, other):
     17         return Rational(self.nom * other.denom - other.nom * self.denom,self.denom * other.denom)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'denom'
```

Comment: Please show the full error traceback, and the call that leads to that error. You may also want to include whether you're using Python 2, Python 3 or have `from __future__ import division`, as that will make quite a difference here (or perhaps just use `//` instead of `/`, assuming you want integer divisions).

Comment: Added, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `Rational(1,2) + 1` uses `__add__` , `1 + Rational(1,2)` uses `__radd__`

Comment: Furas: You're right - when I make that change to the call it works perfectly.  Can you explain why that difference matters here?

Comment: `r` means `right` so if `Rational` is on right size of `+` then Python use `__radd__`. In `__radd__` you doesn't use `other.nom` and `other.denom` but you add `int` to `Rational` so you get correct result.

Comment: in `__add__` use `isinstance(other, int)` to recognize `int` and do different calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Python see `Rational` on left side of `+` then it uses `__and__` but if there is no `Rational` on left size but it is on right side then Python use `__radd__`. (`r` in name `__radd__` means `right`)

In `__add__` you use `other.nom` and `other.denom` which doesn't exists in `int` so `Rational(1,2) + 1` doesn't work.

`1 + Rational(1,2)` works because in `__radd__` you use `other` instead of `other.nom` and `other. denom`

You can use `isinstance(other, int)` to recognize `int` and make different calculation in `__add__` and it will works with `Rational+int` and `Rational+Rational`

```
def __add__ (self, other):
    if isinstance(other, int):
        # Rational + int
        return Rational(self.nom*1+other*self.denom, self.denom*1) 
    else:
        # Rational + Rational
        return Rational(self.nom*other.denom+other.nom*self.denom, self.denom*other.denom)        

# ----

print(Rational(1,2) + 1)
print(Rational(1,2) + Rational(1,2))
```